# How to take parameter "AS IS" in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have this script called readvar.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
a="$1"

echo "$a"
```

I'd want to get the parameter **literally** as user entered,

For example if user runs: `./readvar.sh \\`

It should outputs `\\` without need of enclosing parameter with quotes.

Is that possible?

Comment: The input has been changed before your script even sees it ... you're trying to solve a problem that you can't fix within the script.

Comment: Quoting and escaping is **how** you pass globs and shell meta-characters as string literals to a command without the shell expanding or otherwise acting on them.   i.e. it's not a bug, it's a feature.    BTW, this is basic knowledge about shells that every shell user **should** know - even if what you wanted was possible (it's not), you should not do it because that would be undermining consistency of expectations, your weirdo script would be behaving differently to every other program run from the shell.

Comment: You can use the same trick as in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/631303/edit) -- but you need an alias wrapper for your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `read` with the `-r` flag:

```
-r  Backslash does not act as an
    escape character.  The backslash
    is considered to be part of the line.
    In particular, a backslash-newline pair
    may not then be used as a line
    continuation.
```

So:

```
IFS="" read -r a
echo "$a"
```

will echo "\" if you type "\". It will also keep whitespace (you can remove the IFS bit if that's not the goal).

If you just want to pass it on as a parameter, single quotes should keep the value as-is.

```
./readvar.sh '\\'
```

readvar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="" read -r a
./usevar.sh "$a"
```

usevar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
```

If you type `\\` in `readvar.sh`, `usevar.sh` will echo `\\`.

You need IFS to keep the whitespace at the beginning and end of the text.

Comment: `-r` is not sufficient. You also need `IFS=`, otherwise `read -r` would strip trailing spaces from the line typed by the user. And the `echo $a` is bad too, if the user entered a `*`, they would get something else in return.

Comment: @UncleBilly, good catch! *as-is* should include those. I included your suggestions in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you don't get to do that.

If you run `./readvar.sh \\`, the shell where you wrote the command, parses the command line, recognizes the space as a word separator, and the backslash as quoting the next character (the other backslash). It then ends up with the two words `./readvar.sh` and `\`, and launches the program `./readvar.sh` putting those two words in the argument list of the process that starts. (The command name is argument #0, it shows up in `argv[0]` in a C program.)

Note that you'd get a similar result if the user entered `./readvar.sh '\'` or `bs='\'; ./readvar "$var"` instead, or launched the script with something like `system("./readvar.sh", "\\");` from a Perl program. There's generally no way for the script to know what happened.

---

What you could do, would be to print all the arguments in a format that's suitable as input to the shell, e.g. in Bash with

```
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
    printf "%q " "$@"
fi
echo
```

Note that the output is such that it will work in Bash, but maybe not in a standard shell, since it uses the `$'\n'` form of quoting for newlines etc. Also it will output `\\` regardless of you used `\\` or `'\'` or `"\\"` when starting the script.

Also in Bash, you could misuse the `extdebug` for this. This would arrange the command line as seen by Bash's DEBUG trap to be placed in the environment of the command that runs:

```
export CMDLINE
trap 'CMDLINE=$BASH_COMMAND; true' DEBUG
shopt -s extdebug
```

But note that the command line there is not expanded, so if you run `env abc=$var |grep CMD`, you get to see `env abc=$var`, and not the expanded value.

Of course this won't work if your command isn't launched from a Bash shell that takes that extra step. If you have such a shell higher up in the process tree, `CMDLINE` could be set to the command used to start an earlier command.

---

Now, while those hacky workarounds exist, it would probably better and less surprising for the users of the script to use some other method for achieving what ever it is the script is supposed to do in the end.